# Помогите с логикой в базе данных в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть у таблицы student столбец id_family-это статус семьи(например:полная, неполная)
Есть еще одна таблица family с столбцом name где записаны знач-(Полная,Неполная)
Есть еще одна таблица status с столбцом status где записаны знач-(Родители разведены, Мать-одиночка, Без матери, Без отца)

---

Мне надо их соеденить в student(family)

[image]

Comment: у семьи бывают несколько значении, например Полная но Родители разведены

Comment: или в Неполном несколько значении например без отца, мать одиночка

Comment: Попробуйте как нибудь более понятно написать ваш вопрос. А то даже сложно примерно догадаться о чем речь. Под вопросом есть ссылка "править", воспользуйтесь ей, а не пишите в комментариях

Comment: На вскидку вам надо из студентов ссылаться на таблицу статусов. А family вообще выбросить и обойтись полем да/нет в таблице status

Comment: данный вопрос-картинку следует закрыть, так как ответ на него бесполезен для базы знаний, ведь поисковики (пока) не умеют индексировать смысл, выраженный картинкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [LEFT JOIN](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html), дальше пробегите циклом и соберите данные как вам нужно.

Comment: А почему именно LEFT ? Я не вижу во входных данных ни единого намека, что в studetns могут встречаться значения, отсутствующие в справочниках (family, status).

Comment: Ну потому что вам в конечном итоге нужно получить студентов с параметрами. Студент основная единица в данном случае, поэтому от неё нужно отталкиваться. Соответственно к ней нужно присоединять данные.

Comment: Ну было же сказано что "или в Неполном несколько значении например без отца, мать одиночка", нам нужно их все собрать. значит нужен left

Comment: Не знаю где вы увидели "поле то одно, а не два для отца и матери"

Comment: Я перечитал вопрос. Там еще интереснее. Первое предложение - в таблице _одно_ поле id_family (полная/не полная). И третье предложение - таблица status, которая никак не связана с двумя предыдущими. В данный момент я вообще понимаю вопрос так, что это не о том как сделать выборку, а о том как лучше эту информацию в БД представить, т.е. как переделать структуру БД. В общем надо что бы автор хоть что то пояснил, о чем он вообще спрашивает

Comment: Вы можете изложить все ваши изыскания в своем ответе, или задать уточняющие вопросы. Я это понял так.

Comment: да именно "как лучше эту информацию в БД представить",